# Can I change the voice of OpenEars (iOS)

Tags: ios, openears

Would I be able to change the speaking voice of OpenEars to another? I don't quite like the the default one. Is that possible or would I have to use another API. Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but it's a bit complex process. Openears uses Flite for speech synthesis, so you need to change the voice in Flite. Flite supports [13 voices](http://www.festvox.org/flite/packed/flite-2.0/voices/) to choose already and you have an option to build a new voice.

To build a new voice you need to follow the [documentation](http://www.festvox.org/flite/doc/flite_8.html#Converting-FestVox-Voices). A festvox [documentation](http://www.festvox.org/bsv/) might be also useful for you to understand the basics.

Comment: How would I exactly be able to do that? In the Flite engine, I believe you could use setVoice to change the voice. Is there a similar command in Openears?